# How can I login with facebook via quickblox (PHP)

Tags: quickblox

I read this section http://quickblox.com/developers/Social_Networks_Integration_Manual

But I don't know what to do.If somebody know please help me :)

I was tried with hybridauth I have connection with facebook (my API) hybridauth return to me user information.I create user in quickblox with random password and facebook email and simulate login but this is bad because quickblox in this way don't return to me token and if I want to edit profil I can't....

if( isset( $_GET["login"] ) ){

```
try{

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "facebook" );

        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    }
    catch( Exception $e ){
        die( "<b>got an error!</b> " . $e->getMessage() ); 
    }

    $token = $adapter->getAccessToken();
    //$token['access_token'];
     $nonce = rand();
    $timestamp = time(); 
    $signature_string = "application_id=".APPLICATION_ID."&auth_key=".AUTH_KEY."&nonce=".$nonce."&timestamp=".$timestamp;

        $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $signature_string , AUTH_SECRET);
        // Build post body
        //$post_body = "application_id=" . APPLICATION_ID . "&auth_key=".AUTH_KEY."&timestamp=".$timestamp."&nonce=".$nonce."&signature=".$signature."&user[email]=" . $user_profile->email . "&provider=facebook&scope=friends_status,read_mailbox,photo_upload&keys[token]=".$token['access_token'];
        $post_body = http_build_query(array(
                        'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID,
                        'auth_key' => AUTH_KEY,
                        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                        'nonce' => $nonce,
                        'signature' => $signature
                        ));

        $post_body = "application_id=" . APPLICATION_ID . "&auth_key=" . AUTH_KEY . "&timestamp=" . $timestamp . "&nonce=" . $nonce . "&signature=" . $signature."&user[login]=&user[email]=&user[password]=&provider=facebook&scope=friends_status,read_mailbox,photo_upload&keys[token]=".$token['access_token']."&keys[secret]=";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, QB_API_ENDPOINT . '/' . QB_PATH_SESSION); // Full path is - https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use POST
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body); // Setup post body
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        dump($response);
        if ($response) {
                return $response . "\n";
        } else {
                $error = curl_error($curl). '(' .curl_errno($curl). ')';
                return $error . "\n";
        }
```

This don't work...this is shity they don't have examples :O

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'provider=facebook'  to your **post_body** and **signature_string**

After this - QuickBlox will return HTML page with Facebook login dialog, which you should render to your end users